# Классификация слов

Tags: классификация

Какое практическое значение имеют различные классификации слов, например, прилагательных? Нечеткость и приблизительность определений порождают произвол оценок, ибо каждый специалист имеет свое мнение, часто субъективное(((

Отсутствие конкретности - причина разброда и шатаний. Должна быть четкая, железная классификация - или не должно быть никакой!

Может, Словари есть классификационные, дайте адресок...

Comment: Вопрос отличный! так много по нему рассуждений, но всё же ответа так и нет.
В чём же ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ всех этих классификаций?

Comment: Может, просто человеческому мозгу удобнее таким образом хранить и обрабатывать свои представления? Помнится, я читала книжку о христианстве, там была описана классификация ангелов и других небесных сил. Помнится, их было 3 класса по три вида, всего 9. И какое практическое значение имеет такая классификация? Тем более, что истинность ее вызывает большие сомнения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте статью: [Вопрос о разрядах имен прилагательных](http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200701506). Её суть:

1. попытки классифицировать имена прилагательные восходят еще к XVIII веку;
2. освещение вопроса о разрядах прилагательных до настоящего времени является противоречивым;
3. до сих пор не выявлено единых критериев классификации имен прилагательных, нет цельной картины по вопросу о разрядах прилагательных.
   Мне нравится классификация Валгиной. Качественные - те, которые воспринимаются нами непосредственно(цвет, пространственные понятия, качества-солёный, кислый- черты характера, внешние физические или телесные качества людей и животных). Лексико-грамматические особенности: 1-наличие полной и краткой формы, 2-возможность образования степеней сравнения,3-наличие форм субъективной оценки(уменьшит., ласкат. суффиксов-светлёхонек-), 4-возможность образования наречий на -О,-Е,-волнующе,5-антонимическая пара, 6-возможность образования отвлеч. сущ. с суфф.-от-,-изм-, -ость-,-есть-, -ств-о и др., 7- возможность быть и первообразными, и производными-глазастый-глазастенький.

Относительные - те, которые обозначают признак предмета через отношение к другому предмету: кирпичный, годовой.

Притяжательные - те, которые указывают на принадлежность предмета какому-либо лицу(иногда неодуш. предмету) или животному, а также общую родовую принадлежность и свойство, присущее тому или иному животному. Это позволяет им переходить в разряд относительных и качественных.

Comment: Замечательно! Относительные прилагательные выражают признак предмета через отношение к другому предмету. Волчий аппетит, прилагательное волчий - относительное, 'как у волка', оценочное, но никаким образом не качественное. 'Волчее' аппетит быть не может, краткой формы тоже нет (волч?), так на каком основании 'волчье' прилагательное определяют в качественное? Явный непорядок...

Comment: Почему же? Волчий-не только относящийся к волку, как у волка, но и вообще звериный, т.е. неуёмный, беспредельный, а это уже качественное.

Comment: А кирпичный почто относительное? Кирпичный цвет, 'как у кирпича', красный, налицо явное качество... 
Неужели не бросается в глаза явная неразбериха с терминами? Кирпичный завод и лисий характер, в чем тут загвоздка, не пойму. Качество и относительность - попробуй, разберись! Кожаный диван - это чего?!

Comment: кирпичный цвет - было относительным, а стало качественным, раз цвет.Ведь имеется в виду именно красный, хотя кирпич бывает и белым.Вы правильно определили.Кирпичный завод - где делают кирпичи, кирпичный чай - прессованный кирпичиком - относительное. Лисий характер подруги - свойственный лисе, как у лисы  - относительное, но лисий характер = характер лисы (У меня живёт лиса, и лисий характер мне нравится)- притяжательное.

Comment: В ЕГЭ дают только яркие примеры, школьники понимают, а студенты, если будущие филологи, пусть разбираются, учатся чувствовать смысл, им это надо.А то вон наши учителя начальных классов-заочники покупают контрольные (я же и делаю ), а нам потом за них стыдно, сами безграмотные.Чему детей научат?

Comment: кирпичный цвет и кирпичный дом - разные прилагательные, (омонимы ?)

Comment: >кирпичный цвет и кирпичный дом - разные прилагательные,  

Опять-таки спор о дефинициях. Как ни назови, главное - суть не потерять. А суть тут в том, что прилагательные не подчиняются диктуемым ими грамматичами правилам и дрейфуют из одного разо\ряда в другой, не спрашивая разрешения.  
А то что это именно дефиниции говорит уже то, что разряды прилагательных называют классами, хотя "класс" - это более высокий таксон, надмножество разрядов.   
  
Впрочем, подобных недорахумений в современных грамматиках предостаточно. Путаница с разрядами прилагательных - не самая страшная из проблем.

Comment: DocentI ! В словосочетаниях кирпичный цвет и кирпичный завод - не омонимы, а разные значения одного слова.

Comment: Да, я так и подумала, поэтому и поставила вопрос. Хотя это опять же спор об определениях. По сути "цвета кирпича" и "сделанный из кирпича" - совершенно разные смыслы.